# Is there a way to shuffle a queryset so it shows a different value each day?

Tags: django, django-queryset, shuffle

I'm building a Django 2.5 web app that shows a different quote from an historical figure every day. The problem is that this quote should be different for each user and should change every day without repeating the same quote.

I've already did some research and the only thing that comes close is to use an offset when I request the queryset, but that doesn't solve the random quote for each user problem.

```
quotes/views.py
import datetime

...

now = datetime.datetime.now()
today_tt = now.timetuple()
julian_day = today_tt.tm_yday
#asuming there are 365 quotes on the database
quotes.objects.all()[jualian_day]
```

What can I do to implement this?

Comment: Are the users authenticated and stored in the db?

Comment: Yes, users need to log in

Comment: Adding the pk of the user will give a different quote for each day quotes.objects.all()[ (julian_day + user.pk) % 365 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```python
import random

# TODO Retrieve into pks_used the previously saved primary keys 
# of the quotes already displayed to the current user
pks_used = set()

# Get the primary keys of all quotes
all_pks = set(quotes.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True))

# Exclude the quotes that have been shown already
eligible_pks = all_pks - pks_used

# Get a random quote from the list of unused quotes
# random.sample returns a list 
# (with just one element in our case)
rnd_pk = random.sample(eligible_pks, 1)[0]
todays_quote = quotes.objects.get(pk=rnd_pk)

# TODO display the quote and store its private key in the list of 
# already displayed quotes
```

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. This is what I needed. I made a many to many relationship between the users and quotes that the current user has already seen.